# During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred error occurred

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to try to run a CSV data file

```
traindata = pd.read_csv('preprocessed_train.csv', header=None,low_memory=False)
X = traindata.iloc[0:,1:71]
Y = traindata.iloc[0:,71]
scaler = Normalizer().fit(X)
trainX = scaler.transform(X)
scaler = Normalizer().fit(T)
testT = scaler.transform(T)
```

Why is

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Protocol_6'

printed out, and how do I resolve it?

```
traindata = traindata.astype({"Protocol_6": float})
```

or

```
traindata = traindata['Protocol_6'].astype(str).astype(float)
```

this error occured

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0JMS.png)

Comment: There might be some issues with the column. Could you post some sample data?

Comment: Because column `Protocol_6` has some values that can not be converted to `float`. You can try `traindata['Protocol_6'] = pd.to_numeric(traindata['Protocol_6'], errors='coerce')`

Comment: `Name: Protocol_6, Length: 209715, dtype: float64`  the type changed but the error is still